# An absolute inequality

Tags: solution-verification, triangle-inequality

May I ask is the following correct?

I say, $\forall c,a,\delta\in\mathbb{R},|c-a|-|\delta|\leq |c+\delta-a|\leq |c-a|+|\delta|$ is correct.

Right side:

$\begin{align*}
|c+\delta-a|&=|c-a+\delta|\\
&\leq |c-a|+|\delta|\text{ ,triangle inequality}
\end{align*}
$

Left side:

$\begin{align*}
|c-a|-|\delta|&=|c-\delta+\delta-a|-|\delta|\\
&\leq |c+\delta-a|+|-\delta|-|\delta|\\
&= |c+\delta-a|
\end{align*}
$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, all steps of your proof are correct.